# Do-While Loop Counting 1 to 30 on separate lines in Java

Tags: java, loops, do-while, counting

I am currently in a java class learning about all types of loops, and am stuck on a question specifically on do-while loops. The question asks that we create a do-while loop that counts 1 to 30, with the counting jumping to the next line after 10 integers, for example:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10

11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20

21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
```

I have my loop started, and I can have it print values one through thirty, but I am not sure how to make it skip a line every 10 integers. Here is my current code:

```
int q = 0;
do
{       
    q=q+1;
    System.out.print(q+" ");
}
while (q<30);
System.out.println();
```

Comment: When i print this, it lists all numbers on one line with a space between each number.

Comment: step thru the code with a debugger and see when it executed the println statement.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 9):

Add this line to your code and it will work.

```
if (q % 10 == 0) System.out.println();
```

if `q` is divisible by 10, then you write a line to the system out.

Place it after the line `System.out.print(q+" ");`

Comment: Thanks! I thought that would work, wasn't sure where to put it though!

Comment: @zackadkins put it after the line `System.out.print(q+" ");`

Answer (score 0):

```
    int q = 0;
do
{       
    q=q+1;
    System.out.print(q+" ");

    if(q% 10==0)   {
        System.out.println();
    }
       }
while (q<30);
```

Comment: Use 2 counters is useless

Comment: @azro updated code I took existing code and tried to modify it

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example as to how you can get the line to skip every 10 integers:

```
public class App 
               {
        public static void main( String[] args )throws IOException{
              int y = 1;
              int x = 0;
              do {
                  System.out.print(y + " ");
                  x++;
                  y++;
                  if(x >= 10) {
                           System.out.println();
                           x = 0;
                  }
               }while(y <= 30);

   }



}
```

What we can do is create a "control" variable (x). We can increment it each time during the loop. When x is >= 10, we can print a blank line. We will print each time through while our y variable is <= 30. Here is the output of the program:

```
1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 10 
11 12 13 14 15 16 17 18 19 20 
21 22 23 24 25 26 27 28 29 30
```